# Issue with Hadoop Upgrade from 1.0 to 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I'm trying to upgrade my 5 node hadoop cluster from 1.0 to 2.2.0. When I try to upgrade the namenode using **hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode -upgrade** command and check the log files I get the following error message.

```
    015-03-13 10:02:24,549 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority.
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:347)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:335)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getRpcServerAddress(NameNode.java:388)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loginAsNameNodeUser(NameNode.java:471)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
2015-03-13 10:02:24,586 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-03-13 10:02:24,593 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at nn.cluster.com/192.168.1.75
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your core-site.xml and it should contain valid namenode address.

Comment: @Karthik- Thanks for your response. The core-site.xml does have valid namenode address.                                                                                    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>


<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://192.168.1.75:8020</value>
</property>


</configuration>

Comment: I'm stuck with this for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this value same across cluster and also please provide command you are using to start namenode.

Comment: @Karthik- Yes, I checked core-site.xml on all the nodes. It is same. I'm using the command -hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode -upgrade. Thanks